# React-Bootstrap-Multiselect is rendering a non-functional element

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using React 15.5, and have Bootstrap 4 included in the project.

I'm trying to implement something like this: https://projects.skratchdot.com/react-bootstrap-multiselect/

My code:

```
<Dropdown
    onChange={event => {
        this.setState({
            yearFilter: this.value(this.refs.yieldYears)
        });
    }}
    ref="yieldYears"
    data={[
        { value: 'average', selected: true },
        { value: 2017, label: '2017' },
        { value: 2018, label: '2018' }
    ]}
    multiple
/>
```

My element appears like this:

[image]

The dropdown doesn't work-clicking on the element does nothing.

When I inspect the element, the HTML looks fine.

Is this some sort of Bootstrap version conflict?

Comment: beside the fact that you are not using the current `ref` api: `ref={ref => this.yieldYears = ref}`. what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Clicking on the multiselect does nothing-it doesn't drop down.

Comment: I believe that skratchdot library uses bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing 2 important props: 
`toggle` and `isOpen`.

Example from the [docs](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/):

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dropdownOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
        <DropdownToggle caret>
          Dropdown
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem disabled>Action</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem divider />
          <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that you are using the old [`ref` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).
This is the current `ref` API:

```
ref={ref => this.myRef = ref}
```

And on top of that, i didn't see any `ref` prop in the `react-bootstrap` docs, only an `inputRef` but for input components

Comment: I'm not using reactstrap. I'm using React-Bootstrap-Multiselect, like this: https://projects.skratchdot.com/react-bootstrap-multiselect/